# plotting standard error of the mean with the error bars with plotLMER.fnc

Tags: r, lme4, structural-equation-model

Being new to R, and also to this forum, I apologise if I am posting the question in an unclear manner.

I am using lme4 to run linear mixed model. The model itself works, my problem is in plotting its output with plotLMER, since I would need to add the standard error of the mean with the error bars, but cannot find a way to do it. Thus far, I my code is (data is added below):

```
read.table("data.txt", header=T) -> data
library(lme4)
m1 <- lmer(log(IA_FIRST_RUN_DWELL_TIME) ~ SEMANTIC*SYNTACTIC + (1|SUBJECT) + (1|SENTENCE_ID), data=data);

library(languageR)
plotLMER.fnc(m1, fun=exp, ylab='Dwell time (ms)', pred='SEMANTIC', lwd=3, font= 2, 
         font.lab= 2, xlabs = 2, linecolor = 3:5, 
         intr=list('SYNTACTIC', c('cong','incong'), 'end'),addlines=T)
```

The model works and the plot shows fine, but, as mentioned, I would need to add error bars to it - and this is where I got stuck.

So far I wasnt' able to find an answer to this question anywhere, so any help would be very much appreciated. 
Thanks!
Cata

Example of the data:
SUBJECT SENTENCE_ID IA_FIRST_RUN_DWELL_TIME SEMANTIC SYNTACTIC
s1        1101                     334     cong      cong
s3        1101                     755     cong      cong
s5        1101                     237     cong      cong
s10        2105                     127     cong    incong
s11        2105                     298     cong    incong
s13        2105                     190     cong    incong
s23        3115                     238   incong      cong
s25        3115                     154   incong      cong
s2        3116                     472   incong      cong
s11        4116                     259   incong    incong
s13        4116                     401   incong    incong
s14        4116                     729   incong    incong

Comment: Please also include the data so that we can reproduce what you're seeing. Note that `;` is not necessary in R.

Comment: Thanks for your response and advice! I added an example of the data (in a slightly clumsy way, I'm afraid), since the whole dataset is huge. Hope this could be enough. Thanks again!

Comment: [Here are a few tips](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on how to ask a well formed question. Post enough data to make it instructive (i.e. it demonstrates the problem). Don't forget to include all the code necessary to reproduce what you're after.

Comment: Thanks. Hope it's now ok.